# DTMF not accepted on PHP Agi

Tags: php, asterisk, agi

I am trying to grab the DTMF from user, if its equal to zero then transfer call to an extension else hangup. I have written the following, but it directly plays invalid entry and hangs up my call. Would appreciate help over this matter.

```
$wheretorec = $agi->exec("AGI","googletts.agi,\"To speak to an operator press zero.\",en"); 
$whereto = $agi->get_data($wheretorec, 10000, 1);
$dtmf = $whereto['result'];

if (is_numeric($dtmf ['0'])) 
{
$agi->exec("AGI","googletts.agi,\"Your call is now being transferred\",en");
$agi->exec('transfer',"SIP/123@12.345.678.901:5080");   
$agi->hangup();
} 
else 
{
$agi->exec("AGI","googletts.agi,\"Invalid entry. Please try again later.\",en");
$agi->hangup(); 
}
}
```

Comment: Never heard of asterisk before (looks interesting) but my guess is `if (is_numeric($dtmf ['0']))` not working right. Is `$dtmf['0']` supposed to be numeric? Why are you checking for that? What is the value of `$dtmf['0']` normally? Have you stepped through the code at all?

Comment: i am tryin to verify that if the value input earlier through `$whereto = $agi->get_data($wheretorec, 10000, 1);`
`$dtmf = $whereto['result'];` matches 0 i.e zero then transfer the call to an extension or else fail and hang up.

Comment: try either `$dtmf == 0` or `$dtmf == '0'`. Further, have you tried `var_dump($dtmf)` after you assign `$dtmf`?

Comment: Try `var_dump($dtmf)` and post the output please.

Comment: tried and the script doesnt run, due to error :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have be like this

```
$dtmf = $whereto['result'];

if ($dtmf=="0")
```

Please read corefully phpagi docs and examples

Comment: the code that you have provided that also leads to invalid entry and then hang-up.

Comment: This code is 100% worked and used everywhere in a2billng.org project. Looks like you need improve your php debug skills

Answer (score 0):

```
$dtmfTemp = $agi->get_data("File_name_you_want_to_play", 6000, 1);
$dtmf = $dtmfTemp['result'];
if($dtmf=="0"){
//Do your stuff
}
else{
//Do your other stuff
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to see some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that has worked for me.. if I try anything instead of 'silence/1' or 'beep' then it gives me an error message, invalid entry!

```
$press1 = $agi->get_data('silence/1',50000, 1);
$press1dtmf = $press1['result'];
```